# program which takes any domain name as an input and search it on the browser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

```
import webbrowser

a = str(input("Enter Your Website : ..."))
print(a)

print('Searching '+ a)

webbrowser.open(a)
```

The problem is that it is opening in Firefox, but my default browser is Chrome.
What can be done?

Comment: This explains how the browser is chosen and how you can register() a different one - https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line `webbrowser.open(a)`
you can try this `webbrowser.get('path/to/browser_s_exe_file/you/what/to/open').open(a)`